# Profanity filter blocks unintended words discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here is my current code:

```
if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in bannedWords):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(f"{messageAuthor.mention} your message has been removed as it contains a banned word.")
```

The problem I'm having is it also bans words the contain the banned word, as an example if I ban the word test, testing is also banned because it contains the word test. Anyone have any ideas how to get round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue. How about something like this:

```
import re

def msg_contains_word(msg, word):
    return re.search(fr'\b({word})\b', msg) is not None
```

This function returns true if word is present as a separate word (`\b` are word boundaries). Just use it instead of that check inside `any`

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the thing I was looking for works perfectly now.